# Pull from a remote branch in Jgit with self certificate errors

Tags: java, git, jgit

I have the following code running in a script I am using.

```
 Git git = Git.open(repoLocation);
 Repository repo = git.getRepository();
 git.checkout()
    .setName("feature/test")
    .setStartPoint("remotes/origin/feature/test")
    .call();
 git.pull()
    .setRebase(true)
    .call();
```

However, I am unable to pull from the remote feature branch called "test". How do I go about pulling from this remote branch via Jgit?

After stepping through my debugger, I decided to try and manually pull locally. When typing

```
git pull
```

in my bash terminal, I get the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://username@myCompany.com/path/to/repo.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I now think that this is the root of the error. How do I go about pulling the repo changes locally while still staying secure (*the code runs in an applet that is distributed to others - most answers online say to disable SSL verification but I think that won't work*).

Comment: try to be more specific and post the error messages that you see

Comment: @Shobi Updated! Printed the stack trace and took a look at it further.

Comment: First question, is this code able to pull the master? And the second question, why using "feature/myBranch" instead of "myBranch"? And what the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution was to use RSA authentication when cloning the repository. It solved my issue. I followed [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-authenticate-with-jgit) on how to use RSA authentication, then adjusted what I needed from there.

Note, that I did use a different URL to clone the repo. Instead of using

```
https://username@myCompany.com/path/to/repo.git/
```

I used:

```
ssh://git@My.Company.Com/PATH/repo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

This [tech blog](https://doc.nuxeo.com/blog/jgit-example/) gives the following example on how to deal with branches in Jgit:

```
// Create a new branch
git.branchCreate().setName("newBranch").call();
// Checkout the new branch
git.checkout().setName("newBranch").call();
// List the existing branches
List&lt;Ref&gt; listRefsBranches = git.branchList().setListMode(ListMode.ALL).call();
for (Ref refBranch : listRefsBranches) {
System.out.println("Branch : " + refBranch.getName());
}
// Go back on "master" branch and remove the created one
git.checkout().setName("master");
git.branchDelete().setBranchNames("newBranch");
```

Try performing a `git.fetch().setRemote("origin").call();`, then a `git.checkout().setName("newBranch").call();` before doing the `git pull` and it should work.